# The number of circles that can be drawn out of $10$ points of which $7$ are co-linear

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**My attempt**

The number of cases should be: 
$$10C2+3C2\cdot7C2+3C2\cdot7C1+3C3\cdot7C1+3C3\cdot7C2$$

But the answer is $85$. How?

Comment: (1) Please don't just leave the problem statement in the title; include it in the question as well. (2) Please expound on what the problem statement means. What does it mean to "draw out" a circle?

Comment: The question says that,how many circles can be form using these points

Comment: Using all of the points? Then the answer is zero, because no circle contains 7 distinct colinear points.

Comment: I said using these points not all at a time

Comment: Then infinite. In fact, using just one of the points, I can draw infinite circles passing through that point.

Comment: Condition applied one point =1 circle

Comment: I don't know what "one point =1 circle" means. A point is not a circle.

Comment: I understand you can draw infinite number of circles using a single point but what I am saying is just count them one circle..and what I am asking is how many circles you can draw using different points

Comment: Aha, that's easy. $10$. There are $10$ different points, so you can draw $10$ different circles. Any other circle either doesn't contain any of the $10$ points, so doesn't count, or it shares a point with one of the first $10$, so it counts as "one circle" with one of the first $10$.

Comment: Glibness aside, I suspect you are having trouble with this problem because you (as well as I) don't know exactly what it's asking.

Comment: If you include different point it will be counted in a different circle..I hope you understand now

Comment: Not really. Let me know if this is an accurate explanation of the problem: We're given $10$ points, of which $7$ are colinear. How many ways are there to choose a subset $S$ of the $10$ points such that there exists a circle which passes through all the points in $S$?

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: I hope it would give you a fair idea of what I am trying to say

Comment: I read "If you include different point it will be counted in a different circle." I don't really know what that means.

Comment: Leave it brother..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 non-colinear points are needed to draw a circle.

GIVEN: 10 points are given of which 7 points are colinear.

There are 3 ways this can be done

1) choosing three remaining points that are non co-linear = 3C3 = 1

2) choosing 2 points from the 3 remaining points and 1 point from the 7 colinear points = 3C2 * 7C1 = 3 * 7 = 21

3) choosing 1 point from the 3 remaining points and 2 points from the 7 colinear points = 3C1 * 7C2 = 3 * 21 = 63

Total = 63 + 21 + 1 = 85

Comment: 4 points can also form a circle where no 3 points are collinear..

Comment: yes they do but for that case you need the precise information of the location of that 4th point

Comment: what i meant by 3 non colinear  points are needed is that no matter where the 3 points lies they can always from the circle which is not true for 4 points

Comment: That makes sense...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways that 2 of the non-collinear points can combine with one of the collinear points. There are 2 from 7 ways (21) that 2 of the collinear points can combine with one of the 3 non-collinear points. There is one additional way for the 3 non-collinear points.

$7(3C2) + (7C2)3 + 1$

$(7*3) + (21*3) + 1= 85$

Comment: I want to ask why didn't you include 10C2 in your answer?

Comment: Why you only included 3 non collinear points?